# How to plot a variable from Tkinter program in real-time automatically

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

I have a variable, `current_value` in my Tkinter program. The value of the variable can be increased or decreased using 2 corresponding buttons. I want to plot this variable every 1 second using Matplotlib. So far I've managed to plot the value whenever I press a button, which means that nothing is plotted if I don't press any button. How can I plot the value automatically? (or how could I update the list of values automatically?)

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import *
from matplotlib.figure import *
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.animation as animation

style.use("ggplot")

# Graph
f = Figure(figsize=(5,2), dpi=70)
# Add subplot
a = f.add_subplot(111)

# List that stores value of variable everytime a button is pressed
val_list = []
def animate(i):
    a.clear()
    a.plot(val_list)    # Plots the values according to list

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        # Increase value button
        self.val_incr_btn = Button(self, text="Temp + 1°C", command=self.incr_val)
        self.val_incr_btn.place(x=250, y=35)

        # Decrease value button
        self.val_decr_btn = Button(self, text="Temp - 1°C", command=self.decr_val)
        self.val_decr_btn.place(x=330, y=35)
        
        # Displaying the value of the variable as a number
        self.current_value = 23  # Actual value of variable
        self.value = Label(self, text=str(self.current_value))    # Label that displays the current value
        self.value.place(x=150, y=40)

        # Bring up canvas
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=450, y=0)

    def incr_val(self):
        value = float(self.current_value)   # Convert temp into float
        self.value["text"] = f"{value + 1}"
        self.current_value += 1
        val_list.append(self.current_value)
        return self.current_value

    def decr_val(self):
        value = float(self.current_value)   # Convert temp into float
        self.value["text"] = f"{value - 1}"
        self.current_value -= 1
        val_list.append(self.current_value)
        return self.current_value

root = Root()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=100)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the val_list.append(self.current_value) line into the animate function.

```
# List that stores value of variable everytime a button is pressed
val_list = []
def animate(i):
    a.clear()
    val_list.append(root.current_value)
    a.plot(val_list)    # Plots the values according to list
```

You may want to use a deque instead of a list, for a "rolling" effect.

```
from collections import deque
val_list = deque([], maxlen=200) # start scrolling after 200 datapoints
```